# miniscule annoyance with list comprehension and iterators

Tags: python

Is there a way to write the following expression in way
that I will not repeat the variables twice? it's very annoying
when you have to write it multiple times.

```
['hello {} {}'.format(A,B) for A,B in product(As,Bs)]
```

Comment: fwiw I think striving for such code shortenings makes the code less explicit and harder to reason about. Remember [the zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) `Explicit is better than implicit.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what you would do for a `for` loop anyway isn't it? Anyway, you can use map:

```
map(lambda x:'hello {} {}'.format(*x), product(As,Bs)]
```

I realize now the parameter expansion `*x` syntax might shorten what you wrote above as well (one variable only). If you intend to apply `someFormatString.format(*x)` always you can shorten this using a function to generate your formatter:

```
def mkStr(formatStr):
    return lambda x,f=formatStr: f.format(*x)
```

Then you can map with

```
map(mkStr('hello {} {}'), product(As,Bs)]
```

and switch it up with different format strings.

Comment: @susdu I suggest googling `*args` and `**kwargs`. There are multiple nifty things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

with only a minor change you could get there:

```
['hello {} {}'.format(*ab) for ab in product(As, Bs)]
```

using [`*args`-magic](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html).